# Is it ok to have current dir (with `.vagrant` folder) shared with guest VM?

Tags: vagrant

I want to share current dir in Vagrantfile: `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"`. The `./.vagrant` folder on host with metadata and private key gets accessible to the guest VM then. Is it ok?

I know I could have a dir containing project files like `src/` and share it, but it adds another directory level I'd like to avoid. Or I could use the `VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH` environment variable to have `.vagrant` outside, but that's inconvenient and error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all ok because vagrant does that by default : https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/

> By default, Vagrant will share your project directory (the directory
>   with the Vagrantfile) to /vagrant.

They even mentioned [how to disable it](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html#disabling)

> Disabling the default /vagrant share can be done as follows:
>
> `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true`

Comment: Hm. I accept this answer, but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: where are your concerns ? its not because you share the `.vagrant` directory with information about your VM that bad things will happen.